# Why does Output with RGB on have such a positive effect on my text in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

After I rendered all the JPEG and PNG images for my latest small project I followed my usual workflow in VSE and discovered the encoded video credits were of very poor quality. The credits are composed of **RGBA** PNG images while the main body of the animation are composed of JPEG iamges. After scratching my head a lot and comparing to completed projects with good quality credits I spotted I did not have **RGB** under output ticked on.

[image]

The rest of the animation did not seem to suffer without **RGB** on so I'd like to know why the credits benefited from it? I guess it has to do with the alpha channel of the PNGs.

**Without RGB**

[image]

**With RGB**

[image]

Comment: What was the setting before you chose RGB? I didn't think it was possible to have a null selection.

Comment: Ahh, I see that when switching to ffmpeg output (for movie render) neither BW nor RGB is selected. But I could not return it to the null status. It looks like there is an alpha calculation being missed on the source image. Is there any chance that that this image is keyed?

Comment: I will go and lodge a bug fault for the button I think.

Comment: @3pointedit Good spot on selecting ffmpeg removes colour management. The only effect I had on the credits is a short fade out that you can see here [video](https://youtu.be/kEOV9eiYuMw). Thanks for opening a bug fault.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question more closely ;-)  seems pretty obvious now, lets hope they fix it. Also of note is that this is the default output from the compositor as you need to add an Alpha Conversion node to create premultiplied output (you must do this when sending compositor to VSE as well).

Comment: Follow up to my bug report, it turns out that it is an established setting, see https://developer.blender.org/T52988 however I believe that the ffmpeg preset to a hidden RGBA mode is a bug.